# Changing a dataframe object structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe object in **R**, sample of which is as follows:

```
4   5
4   5
4   5
4   6
4   10
4   10
4   10
4   10
4   9
4   9
4   10
4   10
4   6
4   5
12  3
12  4
12  4
12  4
13  8
13  10
13  9
13  12
13  11
13  13
13  12
13  11
```

From this dataframe, I want to create a new dataframe of **20** columns(to make a heatmap), as follows:

1. Only one row in the new dataframe,for each unique value in `$1`. Hence for this sample data, the new dataframe should have 3 rows(unique 4,12,13).
2. `$2` represents the column number of the new dataframe, in which the frequency of the value(new column number) is to be filled. For example, for 
   `$1` value 4, 5 is repeated 4 times. Hence in the new dataframe, column 5 of the first row should have the value 4.
3. All other column values are zero.

A sample output for this data would be as follows:

```
0 0 0 0 4 2 0 0 2 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can we do this in R? A huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `table`. The 'trick' is to convert your second column to a factor with appropriate levels.

```
df1$X2 <- factor(df1$X2, levels = 1:20)
out <- as.data.frame(table(df1))
```

Here is a way you could plot your result.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(out, aes(X2, X1, fill = Freq)) + geom_tile() + coord_fixed()
```

[image]

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L), X2 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 11L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

From a colleague's help:

```
heatmap_func <-function(df){
levels<-unique(df[,1])
result<-matrix(0, length(levels), 20)
for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
occ<-as.data.frame(table(df[df[,1]==levels[i],2]),stringsAsFactors = F)
for(j in 1:nrow(occ)){
  result[i,as.numeric(occ[j,1])]<-as.numeric(occ[j,2])
}
}
return(as.data.frame(result))
}
```